# ngDraggable - what is the meaning of the values of evt.tx, evt.ty, evt.x and evt.y?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop, draggable, ngdraggable

After dropping an item , there is the 2nd argument of `evt` .

What do these its attributes meaning -`evt.tx`, `evt.ty`, `evt.x` and `evt.y` ?

```
$scope.onDropComplete = function (data, evt) {
    console.log('drop success, data:', data);
    var index = $scope.droppedObjects.indexOf(data);
    if (index == -1)
        $scope.droppedObjects.push(data);
};
```

You can debug it on the follow link , in line 27 after you dropped any item  -  https://codepen.io/beaver71/pen/vLaWLX

Comment: My guess would be start and end locations where t* is the start?

Comment: I don't think so , if do - their difference would be constant , but it change in various drag and drop .